# How to implemet creadit card and debit card payment in salesforce

Tags: paypal, salesforce

I want to implement payment gateway in salesforce for credit card and debit card payments. I have done research and got information only to create paypal buttons. After payment submission i want to get transaction id and message from paypal. How can i achieve this?

Regards
 Reddy

Comment: What did you trie until now?

Comment: I have added generated buy now button code in visualforce page. On click of button it is redirecting to paypal site, here how can i get results from paypal site?

Comment: Didn't paypal provide an API?

Comment: No. How i can get api from paypal?

Comment: I have no experice in paypal development, but I think you have to use some kind of API/Webservice/...

Answer (score 0):

If you are not experienced with API development, paypal API details are here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/

Then the best other option is an App. I have used the connected Epos solution, which is great for taking payments from credit cards, either with the customer present (chip n pin) or by keying in the card numbers. You need to get the PayPalHere card terminal which is about $50, but it is a great all round solution.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000qD0GEAU